# Xamarin Forms MVVM Databinding failing when I'm binding to a single object

Tags: mvvm, data-binding, xamarin.forms

I'm having an issue with data not binding correctly on a details page when I have clicked through from a ListView via a button. The ListView binds perfectly and the object gets passed through to the details page. The Id of the object is read and a full version of the object is called from an API and set to a new instance of the object. When I add a breakpoint, the full object is available, but Labels on the view aren't populated. Here is the ViewModel:

DetailsViewModel.cs

```
public class DetailsViewModel
{
    public Deal Deal { get; set; }
    public int DealId { get; set; }

    public DetailsViewModel(int id)
    {
        Deal = new Deal();
        DealId = id;
    }

    public async void GetDeal()
    {
        var deal = await Deal.GetDeal(DealId);
        if(deal != null)
        {
            Deal = deal;
        }
    }
}
```

The codebehind looks like this:

DetailPage.Xaml.cs

```
DetailsViewModel viewModel;
    int dealId;

    public DetailPage(int id)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        dealId = id;
        viewModel = new DetailsViewModel(dealId);
        BindingContext = viewModel;
    }

    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        viewModel.GetDeal();
    }
```

And the Xaml file is

DetailPage.Xaml

```
 <ContentPage.Content>
    <ScrollView>
        <StackLayout x:Name="detailsLayout">

            <Label Text="{Binding Deal.Name}" />

        </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</ContentPage.Content>
```

When I put a breakpoint in Deal = deal on DetailsViewModel, the Deal object exists and has the correct data, but I just get a blank screen. I have tried Labels with Text="{Binding Name}" and Text="{Binding Deal.Name}".

I have also tried manually creating a deal in the GetDeal function of the ViewModel and still nothing is bound.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Ensure your property Notifies the UI of a change implementing the INotifyPropertyChanged interface. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data-bindings-to-mvvm

2) Ensure the set is done on the UI thread using Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread. https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.device.begininvokeonmainthread?view=xamarin-forms

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace YourNamespace
{
    public class DetailsViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private Deal _deal;

        public Deal Deal
        {
            get => _deal;
            set
            {
                if (_deal != value)
                {
                    _deal = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }
        public int DealId { get; set; }

        public DetailsViewModel(int id)
        {
            //!! useless assignation
            //Deal = new Deal();
            DealId = id;
        }



        public async void GetDeal()
        {
            var deal = await Deal.GetDeal(DealId);

            if (deal != null)
            {
                //Ensure we are on UI thread
                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => Deal = deal);
            }
        }


        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Of course, there's many ways to simplify UI notification codes using inheritance or MVVM framework but that's your choice

Comment: Hi Rudy, that has fixed it thank you. I must admit without having to do either of those things in populating the ListView I did rather ignore the need! I think the key was running the task on the UI thread, I did at one point implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface but took it back out when that didn't work alone!